# How to read a tsp library file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, file-io

I have a tsp library file, that I want to read in javaScript. The file is below:

**file1.tsp**

```
NAME: a280
COMMENT: drilling problem (Ludwig)
TYPE: TSP
DIMENSION: 280
EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE: EUC_2D
NODE_COORD_SECTION
  1 288 149
  2 288 129
  3 270 133
  4 256 141
  5 256 157
  6 246 157
  7 236 169
  8 228 169
  9 228 161
 10 220 169
 11 212 169
 12 204 169
 13 196 169
 14 188 169
 15 196 161
 16 188 145
 17 172 145
 18 164 145
 EOF
```

I only want to read the numbers, and store them in an array like this;

```
node =[1,2,3,4,....]
x=[288,288....]
y=[149,129...]
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We expect people to come to this site with concrete programming problems, and expect them to demonstrate at least some effort towards resolving said problems. If you just want to dump your requirements somewhere and have them implemented, you're probably better off hiring a developer.

Comment: I have a doubt how to remove the top lines I know how to read file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```js
const fileContent = `
NAME: a280
COMMENT: drilling problem (Ludwig)
TYPE: TSP
DIMENSION: 280
EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE: EUC_2D
NODE_COORD_SECTION
  1 288 149
  2 288 129
  3 270 133
  4 256 141
  5 256 157
  6 246 157
  7 236 169
  8 228 169
  9 228 161
 10 220 169
 11 212 169
 12 204 169
 13 196 169
 14 188 169
 15 196 161
 16 188 145
 17 172 145
 18 164 145
 EOF
`;

const linesWithNumbers = fileContent.match(/^ *\d+ +\d+ +\d+$/gm);

const node =[];
const x = [];
const y = [];

for (const line of linesWithNumbers) {
  const numbers = line.trim().split(/ +/);
  node.push(Number(numbers[0]));
  x.push(Number(numbers[1]));
  y.push(Number(numbers[2]));
}

console.log(node);
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```